# How To Integrate ASP.NET MVC Backend To Existing React Frontend In Least Invasive Manner?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, http

I recently joined a team with an existing React.js web project. We want to add a ASP.NET MVC backend to this application, but ideally, we want the option to complete the integration slowly without taking down the existing application for a full refactor.

My question is, **what is the least invasive way to integrate this new backend, if our priority is to rewrite as little of the frontend as possible right off the bat?**

I have seen a lot of information on using Babel to integrate the React.js frontend directly into the ASP.NET MVC file structure, but it might be ideal to keep them as separate projects for now. It does not matter that they compile and build together, we would be fine launching the backend and frontend separately starting out. Really, we would ideally just re-route traffic from our front end to our new backend without changing the front-end project at all.

What we have tried: We did get a ASP.NET MVC backend with a React.js frontend set up using Babel, but wanted to check to see if anybody here has done something similar before copying our entire file structure over.